# Bluetooth LE (Scan) using C++ on OSX?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, bluetooth

I am working with Bluetooth 4.0 LE Beacons and need to scan for Bluetooth LE devices from
within my C++ Application (based on OpenFrameworks). I couldn't find and API documentation for
C++ how to deal with Bluetooth LE yet.

Eventually, I could use also Objective-C code in the C++ project, but I am a C++ developer
and not used to Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the Qt framework's Bluetooth module since you are familiar with C++ and need to work on OSX:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-lowenergyscanner-example.html

An example can be found here so it is easy to get something up and running:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-lowenergyscanner-example.html

Note if accessing the BLE's manufacturer specific data is important to you, you may have to wait until Qt gets those APIs added.